# Setting up a Wiki farm through Virtual Hosts (Apache)

Tags: apache, mediawiki, virtualhost

I'm currently running Mediawiki in my standard Apache folder, that is, /var/www/html.
I've now been tasked to make the Mediawiki multilingual, which I can achieve by creating a wiki farm through setting up technically individual wikis on different subdomains through virtual hosts and then connecting them through Mediawiki extensions.

I've tried experimenting with the virtual hosts recently, though I only got it to work to a degree. That is, I set up and got both VH's enabled through SSH, but having loaded de.example.com and en.example.com, I just got two 404's.

So, before crashing stuff, I just wanted to ask you about my concrete problem:

I want to move the current installation of Mediawiki located at `/var/www/html/` to `/var/www/html/de/`, as well as copy that same installation to `/var/www/html/en/` (for later editing, just to not have to reinstall it again).

And, subsequently, I want de.example.com to point at `/var/www/html/de/` and en.example.com at `/var/www/html/en/`.

Additionally, `example.com` should link to `de.example.com`.

Since I'm currently kind of confused at how to properly achieve this, I'd really appreciate just a quick concrete guide for this specific problem (that is, one that just gets me back on track in a sense?).

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There is no "one true way" to configure a wiki farm using MediaWiki. There are however many different solutions documented at https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Wiki_family.

For a small wiki farm, something like the ["Giant switch statement"](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Wiki_family#Giant_switch_statement) from Manual:Wiki_family is a reasonable way to start. This technique takes advantage of the fact that MediaWiki processes a `LocalSettings.php` file found in the root of the MediaWiki deploy directory very early in the handling of each request and this file can change settings based on *Host:* header or other information found in the request.

To use this method, you would do something like this:

1. Upload MediaWiki files to web folder on the webserver (for example `/var/www/html/`). This has already been done in the original question.
2. Set up initial wiki as usual. For details, see [Manual:Installation guide](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:MyLanguage/Manual:Installation_guide) on mediawiki.org. This too has already been done in the original question.
3. After successful installation, rename the generated LocalSettings.php to make it easy to track which wiki it goes with (for example `LocalSettings_en_example_com.php`)
4. Repeat step two and three above for each wiki you wish to create, creating a new LocalSettings.php file for each wiki and then renaming it to track which wiki it configures (`LocalSettings_de_example_com.php`, etc.)
5. Create a custom `LocalSettings.php` file to select the correct `LocalSettings_*.php` based on the contents of the *Host* header of each request:

   ```
   <?php
   // Include common settings to all wikis before this line (eg. database configuration)

   switch ( $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] ) {
       case 'en.example.com':
           require_once 'LocalSettings_en_example_com.php';
           break;
       case 'de.example.com':
           require_once 'LocalSettings_de_example.com.php';
           break;
       default:
           header( 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found' );
           echo 'This wiki is not available. Check configuration.';
           exit( 0 );
   }
   ```
6. Finally, configure your webserver with multiple virtual hosts, one for each wiki, using the same `/var/www/html` directory as the document root for each virtual host.